# Prove that $Gl_{n}(Z/pZ)$ forms a group under multiplication

Tags: matrices, group-theory

The identity element will belong to the group.

Matrix multiplication is associative.

The closure property will be satisfied as when I multiply two matrices whose coefficients are elements from $Z/pZ$ , as $Z/pZ$ forms a group the elements will belong to the group(not very sure)

How do I show inverse? (I am clear about the idea of how I can calculate the inverse but how do I write it down)

Comment: You should recall that 1. a matrix with entries in a field  is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible in the field 2. for matrices $A, B$ with entries in a field, $\det (AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: It's not exactly clear where you're getting stuck.  Would you be able to answer the question were about $GL_n(\Bbb R)$?  If so, then how is the question about $GL_n(\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z)$ different?

Comment: Isn't $GL_n(k)$ the set of all $n\times n$ invertible matrices over $k$ by the definition? I'm not sure what you are trying to show. How do you define $GL_n(k)$?

Comment: @freakish I want to show that the inverse of any matrix in the Gln(Z/pZ) belongs to the same group

Comment: @GuriaSona that doesn't answer my question at all. $GL_n$ is the set of all invertible matrices to begin with. Obviously the inverse of an invertible matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime number. Then the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $F_p$, which is $\mathcal{M_{n\times n}}(F_p)$ has $GL(n,F_p)$ as a subgroup: the general linear group of dimension $n$ over $F_p$.

Proving that $GL_n(F_p)$ satisfies the group axioms under multiplication can be done here.

1. Every element of this group must be an unit, this is equal to
   $Det(A)\not \equiv_p 0$, so the determinant is an unit on the prime
   field.
2. The previous argument proves the inverse lemma as matrices are
   non-singular.
3. The product of two or more units is an unit, which implies closure
   as the result is an unit on $G$.
4. Associativity works over matrices under multiplication as $A(BC) =
   (AB)C $.
5. The group is non-commutative, so it's not abelian.
6. The $n\times n$ Identity Matrix $I_n$ represents the identity
   element on $G$.